# Spring @Query annotation with enum parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use enum parameter with @Query annotation?

Here is the code I'm using to find user role:

```
Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(Roles.USER);
if ( userRole == null ) {
    LOGGER.debug("No role found with role: {}", Roles.USER);
}
```

and it prints out

```
No role found with role: ROLE_USER
```

but if I try to find all roles this is what I get:

```
for ( Role r : roleRepository.findAll() )
    LOGGER.debug("{}", r);

Role@8a8c0a[roleId=1,role=role_admin,version=0]
Role@1efe9ee[roleId=2,role=role_staff,version=0]
Role@1e70f68[roleId=3,role=role_user,version=0]
Role@a475d1[roleId=4,role=role_guest,version=0]
```

As you can see user role does exists.

RoleRepository:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE LOWER(r.role) = LOWER(:role)")
    public Role findByRole(@Param("role") Roles role);

}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    public enum Roles {

        ADMIN("ROLE_ADMIN"),
        STAFF("ROLE_STAFF"),
        USER("ROLE_USER"),
        GUEST("ROLE_GUEST");

        private String role;

        private Roles(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }

        public String getRole() {
            return role;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return role;
        }

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id", updatable = false)
    private Long roleId;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private long version = 0;

    public Long getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this).toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Back linking with similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44460394/906265

Answer (score 9):

Try using SpEl in Query and call toString() of Enum parameter like this:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE LOWER(r.role) = LOWER(:#{#role?.toString()})")
    public Role findByRole(@Param("role") Roles role);
```

or shorter:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE LOWER(r.role) = LOWER(:#{#role})")
    public Role findByRole(@Param("role") Roles role);
```

Comment: What if I need a list of roles?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest proper use of [JPA enumerated types](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Enumerated). Change the type "role" property as:

```
@Column(name = "role")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Roles role;
```

This should automatically fix the query result.

Comment: Tried this without any success. After enabling more specific logging I got this message: 09:20:28.953 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - ROLE_USER. Does it bind parameter as wrong type?

Comment: Maybe try to use a "String" param in the repository method, instead of the Enum directly. If you use native SQL in the query, try to use "like"

Comment: This question is not about query results. The question is about parameter supplied to the query!