# Can I use enum parameter into JpaRepository nativeQuery?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, enums, spring-data-jpa

Entity looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Application {
@Id
private Long id;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ApplicationStatus status;
}
```

Code works this way:

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
@Query("SELECT app FROM #{#entityName} AS app WHERE app.status LIKE :status")
List<Application> find(@Param("status") ApplicationStatus status);
```

But the same snippet with nativeQuery - doesn't:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT app.* FROM application AS app WHERE app.status LIKE :status", nativeQuery = true)
List<Application> findNative(@Param("status") ApplicationStatus status);
}
```

And I don`t have any exception, just empty list.

How can I fix this? Is it possible to use `enum` with `nativeQuery`?

P.S I can pass `String` into method instead of `ApplicationStatus` but maybe there are another option?

Comment: Do you get any error? After run snippet with nativeQuery, what do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with making a query when using Enum in entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217144/problems-with-making-a-query-when-using-enum-in-entity)

Comment: @the_bluescreen  I don`t have any exception, just empty list

Comment: Using `String` type of `status` parameter into method with nativeQuery instead of enum `ApplicationStatus` is good solution for me.

Comment: Passing the value as a String instead is a workaround, but it would be good to know if there is a better solution. It appears to work as expected if a JPA query, but returns empty results if a native query

Comment: @Tetiana Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 30):

Following [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17242408/906265) with similar requirement and [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650103/906265) pointing to [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) you could use:

```java
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT app FROM #{#entityName} AS app WHERE app.status=:#{#status.name()}")
    List<Application> find(@Param("status") ApplicationStatus status);
}
```

Above important part is `app.status=:#{#status.name()}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but how to handle situation when passing status as null ?

Comment: I would suggest checking it within the curly braces of an expression `#{ ... }` e.g. `#status != null && ...` but I am not sure if expression engine can handle it

Comment: To manage the null values, you need to add "?" : `app.status=:#{#status?.name()}`

Answer (score 23):

To extend on @Aivaras answer:
If you want to use a list of statuses, the SpEL expression is slightly different - you need to do a projection:

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT app FROM #{#entityName} AS app WHERE app.status in :#{#statuses.![name()]}")
    List<Application> find(@Param("statuses") List<ApplicationStatus> statuses);
}
```

Note the change of expression to

```
#{#statuses.![name()]}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you explain the syntax as to how spEL works for collection.?

Comment: @ArunGowda it's called collection projection https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-projection . So out of collection of enums we create collection of strings

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue using `#{#paramName?.name()}`

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from items where type = :#{#type?.name()}", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Item> findByType(@Param("type") EnumType type);
}
 
public enum EnumType { NORMAL, LARGE };
```

Note: the "?" manages the case when the `type` parameter is null.

Answer (score 4):

After a few days with this error, I was able to find the solution.

I did a lot of research and tested in many ways receiving as a parameter `@Param("environment") environment: Environment`:

```
 :#{#environment.TESTING}
 :#{#environment}
 :#{#environment.name()}
 CAST(:#{#environment.name()} as environment)
```

---

## Solution in Kotlin

The key is in the query. **You must to transform the value of the parameter to a String using `.name()` (or receive a String as a parameter) and cast that value of type String to the specific Enum that is needed**. Because passing an object of type Enum directly in the query does not work.

Assuming the Enum in your database is defined as `environment`.

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT some_routine(CAST(:#{#environmentNamedParam.name()} as environment))",
        nativeQuery = true
)
fun yourFunction(
        @Param("environmentNamedParam") environmentParam: Environment
) : Boolean
```

Differentiate between:

- environmentNamedParam
- environmentParam
- environment

---

#spring #jpa #postgresql #kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to string before passing the params.

Comment: As i write above "P.S I can pass String into method instead of ApplicationStatus but maybe there are another option?"

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate 5, I was using the following:

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT app FROM #{#entityName} AS app 
WHERE app.status=:#{#status?.name()}")
    List<Application> find(@Param("status") ApplicationStatus status);
}
```

But this doesn't work anymore with Hibernate 6 (tested with 6.2.9, maybe due to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17006), so now I'm using the following (the enum is passed as String to the native query, and the enum->name conversion is done in a default method; requires Java 8):

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT app FROM #{#entityName} AS app 
WHERE :status IS NULL or app.status=:status")
    List<Application> find(@Param("status") String status);        

    default List<Application> find(@Param("status") ApplicationStatus status) {
        return find(status != null ? status.name() : null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

how about this?

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
List<Application> findByStatus(ApplicationStatus status);
```

Comment: In my question I use simplified example, my real code way more complicated and I need to use 'nativeQuery'.