# Spring Boot JPA native query for enum values

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a native query to search from a table based on EnumType entity. This ENUM MealType is a part of @Table Meal.

```
@Column(name = "meal_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MealType mealType;
```

Now, my query is:

```
@Repository
public interface MealRepository extends JpaRepository<Meal, Long> {
@Query(value ="select * from meal m where m.meal_type = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Meal> findMealByType(MealType mealType);
```

}

But when I run a test on it I keep getting `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet`

Apart from that, I have also tried to re-write the query with MealType as a parameter:

```
  @Query(value ="select * from meal m where m.meal_type in :meal_type ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Meal> findMealByType(@Param("meal_type") MealType mealType);
```

> but it caused a different kind of error

`InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select * from meal m where m.meal_type in ? ]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

I would expect that there is some problem somewhere else, but the same customized query with search based on ID  works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `List<Meal> findMealByType(String mealType);` ?

Comment: but I need to pass Enum as a parameter

Comment: @VladDemyan why do you use `nativeQuery` ?

Comment: you use spring data jpa, why not `findByMealType(MealType mealType);` nothing to add.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use enums and SQL. You have to pass the parameter as String:

```
@Repository
public interface MealRepository extends JpaRepository<Meal, Long> {

    @Query(value ="select * from meal m where m.meal_type = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Meal> findMealByType(String mealType);
```

Comment: you actually can: :#{#mealType.name()} see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460394/can-i-use-enum-parameter-into-jparepository-nativequery

Comment: Do you have any reference doc for this answer?

Answer (score -3):

```
@Repository
public interface MealRepository extends JpaRepository<Meal, Long> {

    @Query(value ="select * from meal m where m.meal_type = :mealType", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Meal> findMealByType(@Param("mealType")MealType mealType);
}
```

Comment: "m.mealType = :mealType" ? @chillworld

Comment: Add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.