# How to use Hibernate 6 short hand syntax to simplify JPA query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

According to this [post comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644340/hibernate-throws-query-semanticexception-on-enum-compare-could-not-interpret-pa#comment133478180_75652371), Hibernate 6 introduced support for the short hand syntax:

> In Hibernate 6 we introduced support for the short hand syntax. For Hibernate 5 I believe that you have to use the FQN in HQL...

Unfortunately I cannot find anything on the Internet that explains how to replace a fully qualified name inside a JPA query using short hand syntax.

So the initial situation would be something like this:

```
@Query("""
        SELECT email
        FROM UserEmail email
        WHERE email.emailStatus.description = com.example.entity.EmailStatus$Description.ACTIVE
        """)
Optional<UserEmail> findAllWithActiveStatus();
```

And as you might guess right, `Description` is an enum which lives as an inner class inside `EmailStatus`. Now the goal would be to get the where-clause down by the use of short hand syntax to something like that:

```
@Query("""
        SELECT email
        FROM UserEmail email
        WHERE email.emailStatus.description = Description.ACTIVE
        """)
Optional<UserEmail> findAllWithActiveStatus();
```

Can anyone explain to me what Christian Beikov might have meant by his statement regarding the new Hibernate 6 short hand syntax and how I can use this feature to simplify my code?

**Many thanks in advance for any help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT email
FROM UserEmail email
WHERE email.emailStatus.description = ACTIVE
```

The type of `ACTIVE` will be inferred from the type of the `description` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about inference. Is there a way to get Hibernate recognizing that we deal with an inner class, like in this special case? Unfortunately, it seems that inference allone is not sufficient, since I get the following `SemanticException`:
`org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'com.example.entity.EmailStatus.Description.ACTIVE'. I think, the proper path expression should be `com.example.entity.EmailStatus$Description.ACTIVE`.

Comment: I mean if that is the message, the you have not used the query I just gave you. In the query I just gave you, the expression is `ACTIVE` not `com.example.entity.EmailStatus.Description.ACTIVE`. And yes, if you have an inner class, it should be a `$`, not a `.` i.e. `EmailStatus$Description`.

Comment: Yes, I've understand correctly, I've just used the expression as you meant. To be exactly clear, the where-clause looks as follows: `WHERE email.emailStatus.description = ACTIVE`. But nevertheless, Hibernate then seems to construct via inference an expression by itself with the following fully qualified expression: `com.example.entity.EmailStatus.Description.ACTIVE` (note that this expression build by Hibernate does not have the $-sign separator but inserts just a dot for concatenation).

Comment: The result is the SemanticException like mentioned above. So if the beahavior should be as you meant, Hibernate seems to have a bug ;)

Comment: I mean, that's _possible_ of course, but it's pretty difficult to believe, since we have tests for this, and I just tested it myself in 6.3 and it works perfectly, just as advertised. There might be something weird about your mappings, which you have not shown in the problem description.

Comment: You are right, new releases of Hibernate don't suffer from this bug anymore. I'm using Spring Boot (3.0.6 - the latest stable version) which pulls `hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final`, and this  very Hibernate version isn't able to resolve the path correctly. Manually updating Hibernate to `hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final` solves that problem. I'm sorry bothering you, but I was really thinking Spring Boot is getting developed bullet-proof - at least in combination with the most important dependencies like Hibernate or Jackson. My fault, always expect the unexpected. MANY THANKS !!!